# unable to fetch json data from $http post method in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, post

I am unable to fetch json data from $http post method in angularjs
I had try following code in my controller file

```
var sectionTypeVM = new Object();
            sectionTypeVM.sessionid = 'Session';
            sectionTypeVM.query = 'where LOB group by Report_Source_Type,Report_Object_Type';
           // alert(JSON.stringify(sectionTypeVM));
            $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://testserver/search',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(sectionTypeVM),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('success');
                alert(data);
                })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('error');
                  alert(data+ status + headers + config );
            });
```

My $http request return error function when called.
I am using AngularJS v1.2.16

Thanks
Gajanan

Comment: And what is the error? You're alerting the arguments to the error function. What do they say? You have access to the request and the response via the Net tab of your browser's developer tools. Are they the request and response that you expect?

Comment: You don't need to stringify the JSON when you add it to the `data` in your `$http`.

Comment: I am getting in error alert status = 0 and headers =  `function (name) {
"use strict";
    if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);
    if (name) {
      return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
    }
    return headersObj;
 }[object Object]`

Comment: When i call $http request and check in fiddler its shows request header is OPTIONS /search HTTP/1.1 instead of POST and I don't see json request getting passed to server

Comment: I want to add some more details to this question, we work together, we are trying to make this REST API call different from original domain server, so in this case test server maps to domain different the web site. Is this CORS related issue? Is there any settings we need to enable in AngularJS to enable cross domain API invoke?